# Meteorjs - Separated interface for Webapp and Mobile app

Tags: meteor, ddp

I have this project with Web-app is already done, so I am gonna start mobile app development work, planning to use Famo.us

My question is that I know I could make a separated mobile app project and connect it thru DDP, but I am a bit confused amid the articles on this topics, so was wondering if anyone can give a good overview on how to tackle this problem?

Or is there a better solution for someone in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy. To run Cordova specific code you just need to check if you're in Cordova.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#adding-cordovaphonegap-specific-javascript-code-to-your-application

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  console.log("Printed only in mobile cordova apps");
}
```

Comment: ya, but that sound like a really messed up code as well as I think the size of app will be bigger than needed?

Comment: You can either build your app to only have cordova code, or you can build your app to have client code and cordova code. That's your choice. What you asked is how to do cordova specific code and I gave you an answer.

Comment: can u build a seperated purely cordava client thing that connect to the webapp server?